# Trying to open and close folder icon in collapse using jQuery and bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

am trying to open and close folder icon in collapse using  jQuery and bootstrap 4 buts is not working
here's my code
in javascript

```
$('div#accordion').on({
  'shown.bs.collapse': function() {
    $('#table_category_ajax .card-header').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
       $(this).css({'background' : '#FFEEBA', 'color' : '#000'});
         $(this).find('span#_category-folder').attr('class', 'far fa-folder-open');

    }
   });
  },
  'hidden.bs.collapse': function() {
    $('#table_category_ajax .card-header').css({'background' : '#F7F7F7', 'color' : '#000'});
    $('span#_category-folder').attr('class', 'far fa-folder');
  }
});
```

in blade.php

```html
<div id="accordion" class="table-responsive container">
  <div class="container">
    <table id="table_category_ajax" class="table mt-4 mb-0" cellspacing="0"
           cellpadding="0">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col" scope="col">#</th>
        <th class="col" scope="col">{{ __('messages.category name') }}</th>
        <th class="col" scope="col">{{ __('messages.date') }}</th>
        <th class="col" scope="col">{{ __('messages.products_count') }}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  @foreach ($category as $item)
  <div id="table_category_ajax" class="card rounded-0 mt-0">
    <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse"
         data-target="#collapse{{ $item->id }}" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          {{ $item->id }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ $item->name }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ $item->created_at->format('M d Y') }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <span class="badge badge-info rounded-0 mr-1" data-toggle="tooltip"
                data-placement="right"
                title="@lang('messages.category_tooltip')"
          > {{ count($item->product) }} </span>
          <span id="_category-folder" class=""></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse{{ $item->id }}" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        @if ( count($item->product) == 0 )
        <table class="table table-hover text-center mt-4" cellspacing="1"
               cellpadding="1">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col text-center">{{ __('messages.no_products') }}</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
        @else
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm mt-0"
               cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <thead class="bg-info text-white">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">{{ __('messages.product Name') }}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{ __('messages.product cost') }}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{ __('messages.product Quantity') }}</th>
            @php
            if($item->id == 3 || $item->id == 4 || $item->id == 5)
            echo "
            <th scope='col'>". __('messages.product price') ."</th>
            ";
            else {
            echo "
            <th scope='col'>". __('messages.product Barcode') ."</th>
            ";
            }
            @endphp
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          @foreach ($item->product as $productitem)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $productitem->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $productitem->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $productitem->cost }}</td>
            <td>{{ $productitem->quantity }}</td>
            @php
            if($item->id == 3 || $item->id == 4 || $item->id == 5)
            echo "
            <td>". $productitem->price ."</td>
            ";
            else {
            echo "
            <td>". $productitem->barcode ."</td>
            ";
            }
            @endphp
          </tr>
          @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

but icon not working closing and open it's still opened all the time in the collapse closed...
The background color works fine one collapse but the icon does not
someone can help me?

Comment: For starters, you have two elements with the same ID (id="table_category_ajax")

Comment: I change the id .. but still not working

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that shows the problem? You have a lot of HTML that is not pertinent to the problem. Plain HTML, no PHP.